# Unable to change BIOS settings Lenovo Z50-70 (Bug #1734147)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, 17.10, bios

I have a Lenovo Z50-70 and I got affected by Bug #1734147: I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and it blocked my BIOS, now I can't boot from USB or DVD and I'm not able to change boot order or disable secure boot.

I found a possible solution here [corrupted BIOS due to Intel SPI bug in kernel | bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) but it doesn't fit my needs. In fact, not being an expert, I noticed something working badly on the PC and I decided to delete Ubuntu thinking that after deleting it I would be able to boot again and reinstall it.

Anyway I still wasn't able to boot and I thougt it was due to GRUB still appearing and I deleted that also. Just after all these operations I found that my problem was due to a bug, but without Ubuntu on my pc now I'm not able to apply the proposed solution to my problem.

On [How to boot from USB with Grub2 | viktorpetersson.com](https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/07/29/how-to-boot-from-usb-with-grub2.html) I found another guide to force boot from usb but in order to make it work you need grub2 and I can't boot it due to secure boot.

Does anyone know a solution to that bug that could work in my situation? (I still have access to Windows)

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Have you tried 17.10.1?

Comment: I'd like to, but I can't boot anything but windows at the moment (and that one is the biggest problem)...

Comment: Try burning a 17.10.1 ISO to DVD in Windows. Reboot. Try holding the F12 key (the F key may be different on your machine) to bring up an interactive boot menu. Select DVD. Install 17.10.1.

Comment: tried but It didn't worked... It seems like boot from everithing but hdd is disabled. I only have access to windows at the moment

Comment: Go to the Lenovo web site and download and install the latest BIOS. Hopefully it's a Windows installer. See if that fixes the problem. Otherwise, you may have to remove the HDD so that it'll boot the Ubuntu Live DVD from your CD/DVD drive, and then maybe you can try something else/more.

Comment: already tried to flash the BIOS but it does't work, the pc reboot normaly without flashing; about the HDD thanks, good idea I will try today if I can. Anyway thank for helping me andd for your time :)